# Enter n different positive numbers. Calculate the average value of all prime numbers among them. [Python]

Tags: python

I need to do as the title suggests however I have ran into a problem. This is my code so far:

```
#Input
n = int(input('Enter n: '))
#Prime = 0
p = []
#Loopidty
for i in range(n):
  #Ask user to input x
  x = int(input('Enter a Number: '))

#Check if prime
  if x < 2:
    print('The number is not prime.')
  else:
      for n in range(2, x - 1):
          if x % n == 0:
              print('The number is not prime.')
              break
else:
          print('The number is prime.')
          p.append(x)
#Answer
Answer = sum(p) / n
print('The answer is: ', Answer)
```

The issues is when I add the prime numbers to the list it only adds the first number and stops there, how do I combat this?
Many thanks

Comment: Indents are broken, but it seems you try to decide if the number is prime inside the loop (for n in range(2, x - 1)). You cannot. You may do it only after this loop. You may use an additional flag, raise it inside the loop if the number is not prime and append only if flag was not raise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good idea to break your code into smaller parts. We can create a function to check if a number is prime or not and check that it is correct. After that just add the rest of the code.

```py
import math

def is_prime(x):
    """Check that a number `x``is prime"""
    #                 You only need to go up to sqrt(x)
    for n in range(2, int(math.sqrt(x) + 1)):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True

# xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
sum = 0.0
num_entries = 0  # Number of prime numbers entered by the user
n = int(input('Enter n: '))

for i in range(n):
    x = int(input('Enter a Number: '))
    if is_prime(x):
        sum += x
        num_entries += 1

if num_entries == 0:
    print("You didn't enter any prime number")
else:
    print("The average of the entered prime numbers is ", sum / num_entries)
```